# PHP Connection with SQL Server 2008 in Windows10

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect PHP with SQL Server 2008 but I am unable to establish the connection.

I followed the following tutorials:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139(v=sql.90).aspx

My PHP.ini

[image]

My Dll and location:

[image]

My PHP Version:
[image]

My Extensions are showing in WAMP PHP Extensions:

[image]

But when I try the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$serverName = "SAPSRV"; //serverName\instanceName

// Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
// The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"SmartLogistic");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

I am still getting the following Error:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in
>   H:\wamp\www\job\sql.php

Help me in Solving the issue, Thanks in Advance..

Comment: @PaulCrovella I wanted to make sure that i did everthing correctly.. so giving more options to others to find my fault using image is not bad so that only i tried..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same error a few months back and here is what worked for me.

First of all for the sqlsrv driver to work you will need 32bit WAMP Server it does not work with 64bit WAMP.

I used the php_sqlsrv_55_ts DLL file which I am able to run my queries within PHP on WAMP.

Now here is where it gets interesting. I am assuming you are going to be running  your system on a Linux based server?

If it is the case sqlsrv does not work on Linux based OS so you will have to use the mssql driver on Linux OS. [Here is a link](http://kogentadono.com/2011/11/01/installing-the-mssql-libraries-for-php-on-linux/) to set it up.

Finally you will need to code a custom function which checks your PHP extensions and then depending where you are running them from choose the correct driver.

Here is a function I created to see which drive is loaded and determine which one to use.

```
// Function to check which MS SQL database driver is loaded
function get_db_loaded_extension() {
    // Assign php loaded extensions to an array variable
    $php_loaded_extensions_array = get_loaded_extensions();

    // Loop through each php extension in the array
    foreach($php_loaded_extensions_array as $php_ext) {
        // Switch to check which MS SQL database driver is loaded
        switch($php_ext) {
            case "mssql":
                $return = "mssql";
                break;

            case "sqlsrv":
                $return = "sqlsrv";
                break;
        }
    }

    // Check if a MS SQL database driver have been found
    if(!isset($return)) {
        $return = js_dialog("No Microsoft SQL database driver loaded.");
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Just as an example also here is how you can create the connection.

```
// Call function to check which MS SQL database driver extension is loaded
$mssql_db_driver = get_db_loaded_extension();

// Switch to determine how to make the appropriate connection
switch($mssql_db_driver) {
    case "mssql":
        // Set the MSSQL database variables
        $mssql_servername = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
        $mssql_username = "my_user";
        $mssql_password = "**********";

        // Create conection to MSSQL using the mssql php extension
        $mssql_conn = mssql_connect($mssql_servername, $mssql_username, $mssql_password);
        break;

    case "sqlsrv":
        // Set the MSSQL database variables
        $mssql_servername = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
        $mssql_conn_info = array(
          "UID" => "my_user",
          "PWD"=> "**********"
        );

        // Create conection to MSSQL using the sqlsrv php extension
        $mssql_conn = sqlsrv_connect($mssql_servername, $mssql_conn_info);
        break;

    default:
        echo $mssql_db_driver;
        break;
}

// Check the MSSQL connection
if(!$mssql_conn) {
    exit("Could not connect to the database. Please contact the administrator.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with php rather than sql. sqlsrv_connect is an unknown function so it cannot be called. Try using PDO to start with. Its a nicer and safer way to interact with an SQL database.
http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

The following should allow you to query a sql server db.

```
$dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Table");
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in H:\wamp\www\job\sql.php on line 7
( ! ) PDOException: could not find driver in H:\wamp\www\job\sql.php on line 7

Comment: Hasting I tried ur code and received trhe above error.

Comment: You are missing the sql server driver. http://www.microsoft.com/en-IE/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: @DanHastings, Right. Hence why all the screenshots in the question are of the asker trying to install them.

Comment: The exception you are getting would suggest otherwise. Make surethat you do not have 2 versions of PHP on your system. I can see that you have the mysql drivers installed, but your code is not able to find them. Run a phpinfo() to see what drivers your code is able to pickup.

Comment: i run the phpinfo and i dont see sqlsrv.. :(

Comment: i think you have some errors with PHP so. Try to install the driver i provided in the link above. Restart apache (stop first then start). If it still does not work you may need to reinstall php